# Cannot find functions from ez library

Tags: r

I am trying to use the functions ezPrecis and ezPlot from the [ez library](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ez/ez.pdf). I install the library without any problems:

```
install.packages(c("ez"))
```

and I import the library:

```
library(ez)
```

but when I run my code, e.g.

```
ezPrecis(d2)
```

I get the error:

```
Error: could not find function "ezPrecis"
```

and the same with ezPlot. Any ideas?

Comment: does it also happen for: `data(ANT2); head(ANT2); ez:::ezPrecis(ANT2)`?

Comment: Probably the library missing or not loaded. Edit your post with `sessionInfo()`, to see if the library is loaded.